# jmeter Root CA certificate alert repeatedly

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to Record script with jmeter Test Script recorder.
I added RootCA certificate to browser by following the steps (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
But  still when i Start to record its again giving me alert to install Root CA certificate,
Any suggestions please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the alert you're talking about is the popup in jmeter that pops when you start recording then there's nothing you can do about it, jmeter doesn't know about your browser certificate install.

Note it's an information popup, so if you did what it advises you can ignore it